# Java Maven Jar-java.sql.SQLEXception : No suiteable driver found for jdbc:mysql

Tags: java, mysql, maven, jdbc

When I run my code program **JAVA MAVEN** on neatbean it worked.But when I build and run file jar it then appeared error in cmd

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.driver**

**java.sql.SQLEXception : No suiteable driver found for jdbc:mysql**

I have found the error on stackoverflow for file jar maven java,but failed

```
public Connection connect() {
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="comment">
    try {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + localhost + ":3306/" + database + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, username, pass);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

In the configuration pom.xml file I used

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How do you set your classpath when you run the jar? Are dependencies bundled in?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: Yes.I installed classpath,It has run successfully,but because of my program database connected to it was a error when run file jar

Comment: You have to set up these things yourself when you run outside of the IDE. Easiest way is to build an executable jar with dependencies. (easiest to run, not easiest to build...)

Comment: Did you mean to use java maven as a library and use java swing to use it?

Comment: before you run your program do you see the jar file for mysql connector (mysql-connector-java-5.1.37-bin.jar) in one of your lib folders ?

Comment: Thilo if you are reading this article, let me thank you very much. I have read your article and I've found answers for your answer